# Set bitrate for automatic recoding mp3 in Amarok

Tags: sound, music-player, amarok

I have a portable audio player that has limited set of audio decoders. It's a [Sandisk Sansa View](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37/~/sansa-view-supported-formats-and-codecs) with 32 Gb of internal and 32 Gb of external capacity. The version of my Amarok is versie 2.8.0. I am using Amarok because Rhythmbox doesn't detect the player in MSC mode.

Only when I connect the player in MSC mode, a .is_audio_player file is made. I suppose this is done by Amarok after accepting the device as audio container. I edited according to the website of [Almost a Technocrat](http://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.be/2010/11/isaudioplayer.html#.VjX6KZduN5E) using the listed [MIME](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)-types. The contents of the edited file are below

```
ascii_only=true
audio_folder[$e]=./MUSIC
collection_name=Sansa View
ignore_the=false
music_filenamescheme=%artist%/%album%/%track% %title%
output_formats=audio/mpeg,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/wav,audio/aac,audio/x-aac
playlist_formats=audio/m3u
playlist_path=./PLAYLISTS
regex_text=
replace_spaces=false
replace_text=
use_automatically=true
vfat_safe=true

[transcoding]
Encoder=INVALID
TrackSelection=0
```

Problems:

- When dragging FLAC files no dialog appears, asking for re-encoding.
- In the end the files are just stored as FLAC which is an unreadable format to the device as mentioned in the above configuration file.

The first thing I would do is experiment with the `[transcoding]` section as documented in [KDE API](http://api.kde.org/extragear-api/multimedia-apidocs/amarok/html/classTranscoding_1_1Configuration.html), but it should work out of the box if I remember well. I did find other values for `Encoder=INVALID` in the [documentation](http://api.kde.org/extragear-api/multimedia-apidocs/amarok/html/namespaceTranscoding.html#a717673d8ed1b59b6782812a9e35e340d) and set it to `Encoder=MP3`. Unfortunately, the same problem appears.

I am thinking the INVALID was put their to express a lack of encoding functionality. Could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was missing encoding functionality indeed. Particularly the one for QT apps. Is that correct? Below is an extract of my `/var/log/apt/history.log` saying all the stuff I installed related to transcoding, gstreamer, encoding, qt, and so on.

```
Start-Date: 2015-11-01  13:50:52
Install: libavresample-ffmpeg2:amd64 (2.7.2-1build1, automatic), kubuntu-restricted-extras:amd64 (64), libunicode-string-perl:amd64 (2.09-5build2, automatic), mp3fs:amd64 (0.91-1build1), libmp3-info-perl:amd64 (1.24-1, automatic), libpgm-5.1-0:amd64 (5.1.118-1~dfsg-2ubuntu1, automatic), libavdevice-ffmpeg56:amd64 (2.7.2-1build1, automatic), libimage-exiftool-perl:amd64 (10.00-1, automatic), libmp3-tag-perl:amd64 (1.13-1, automatic), libterm-readline-gnu-perl:amd64 (1.24-2build1, automatic), libcanberra-gstreamer:amd64 (0.30-2ubuntu2), libzmq3:amd64 (4.0.5+dfsg-3ubuntu1~gcc5.1, automatic), gstreamer0.10-tools:amd64 (0.10.36-1.5ubuntu1), lltag:amd64 (0.14.4-2), ffmpeg:amd64 (2.7.2-1build1), libsodium13:amd64 (1.0.3-1, automatic), easymp3gain-qt:amd64 (0.5.0+svn135-6), flac:amd64 (1.3.1-4), mp3info:amd64 (0.8.5a-1, automatic), libid3tag0:amd64 (0.15.1b-11, automatic), vorbisgain:amd64 (0.37-2, automatic), qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5:amd64 (1.2.0-3), vorbis-tools:amd64 (1.4.0-6ubuntu1, automatic), libavfilter-ffmpeg5:amd64 (2.7.2-1build1, automatic), libqt4pas5:amd64 (2.5-14, automatic), easymp3gain-data:amd64 (0.5.0+svn135-6, automatic), qtgstreamer-plugins:amd64 (1.2.0-3)
End-Date: 2015-11-01  13:51:38
```

## Missing transcoding libraries

Apparently it solved my problem by making the dialog appear in Amarok, but not all packages will be necessary. I think `ffmpeg` and `libqt4pas5`, `gstreamer0.10-tools` where the main ones. This makes it possible as well to change the parameters inside of the .is_audio_player file used by most Audio Collection managers on Ubuntu using a GUI.

## Remaining bugs and solutions

### Amarok

Still FLAC gets transfered when selecting "if accepted" in the dialog, even if it's not accepted in the config file. So I have to manually select all my non-accepted files in Amarok before transferring. A solution is to set transcoding functionality to "transcode non-mp3's to mp3" in het collection

### Sansa View

Connecting the device in mtp causes an error displayed by Ubuntu because "the cache cannot be updated". I should be able to do all this trancoding in mtp mode as well? Now I have to be sure I mounted it in MSC mode (by holding the left-key for 5 seconds in HOLD after connect).

Music on the external sdcard should be stored in a subfolder MUSIC (using MSC mode of course). Otherwise the tags are not recognized.